# Retrieving a flag from vim commands by reading through strace output [CTF]

Tags: linux, ctf

So, to clarify, I'm currently working on a CTF challenge that consists of running an strace over on a bash script that is running vim commands using commands like vim -c ":!cat flag.txt" inside of a bash script. For some clarity, this idea was heavily inspired by a CTF I did recently and here's a writeup of what it looked like and did if you'd like to see what I'm really going for(https://github.com/Dvd848/CTFs/blob/master/2019_36C3_Junior/tracer.md). I'm not quite sure how to get the proper output from the vim commands to obfuscate the flag. I'd like it to recognize each keypress as reads and writes, but haven't found a solid approach to accomplish this cleanly. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Essentially there would be an strace output where the flag could be seen being written using vim. I'm not 100% sure this can even be done properly through bash, so any suggestions would be very helpful!